# SonarQube - Sonar way Coverage over leak period fails even when no modifications occur on codebase

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

Maybe this is my ignorance in understanding the Quality Gate, but I have a failing quality gate due to the default 40% Coverage over leak period when using the sonarway code quality gate via VSTS build. The issue is that there has been no modifications to the code between the initial analysis and the latest analysis, so to reference the metaphor in the docs.. there is no additional water in the kitchen.. hence I am not seeing a reason for this criterion to be failing.

Has anyone else experienced this and/or can anyone explain the logic if this is indeed the expected behavior? IMO, I would expect the Leak Period Code Coverage check to not apply when no modifications have occurred on the code base during the leak period.

My SQ analysis is being executed via VSTS and the version of SQ is 6.7.3.

Summary of Analysis with failing QG due to coverage leak (also the percentage coverage is still the same)
[image: Quality Gate Overview with Coverage failure]

The issue also occurs when there are code modifications and those specific modifications have 100% code coverage
[image: 100% Coverage on New Code also fails]

The sonarway quality gate configuration is as follows (default configuration):
[image: sonarway quality gate configuration]

As requested, I have also created a simple demo project which also demonstrates the behavior (running builds with SQ analysis and the second build fails due to 0.0% coverage over leak period although there is no new code). Sample project can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnqrFWQ4F-9KrDBFi9u5arBh-_Pq)

Appreciate if someone can explain this behavior to me as it seems contrary to the documentation.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot to show your Quality Gate "SonarQube way"? And can you also share an example project in one drive which can reproduce the same SQ analysis result?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT added the additional info as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, it turned out to be a bit of a red herring!

Following some good discussions with colleagues we were all in agreement that a **coverage** gate condition with **Over Leak Period** set to always was an incorrect gate configuration.

I was under the false assumption that the SonarQube way was the built-in default and was not editable. It turns out however, that the gate is in fact editable. *Read-only* mode was only enforced from v7.0 onwards as per [release notes](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+7.0+Upgrade+Notes). So the root cause of our misconfiguration is still under investigation but we can be sure that it's not the default and recommended Gate as per SonarQube [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates)

In the example posted above, the gate complains that the additional 0.7% coverage is below the minimum 40% error level. The condition itself is applying as configured but it really should be impossible to enable leak period for coverage. Instead the **Coverage on New Code** should be used.

So the simple one liner solution:
Make sure **Over Leak Period** is set to never (and/or not selected) if using the **Coverage** condition